# Print invisible content of the webview in windows8

Tags: c#, xaml, printing, windows-8, webview

I have a webview in my xaml, due to the size of the webview, it couldn't display all the html content once, so there's a scrollviewer. I want to print all the content of the html file, but when I select a printer in the device charm, the preview page only displays the content which currently displays in the webview, the invisible content couldn't displays in the preview pages, anyone can help? Below is my code.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    PrintDocument printDocument;
    IPrintDocumentSource printDocumentSource;
    WebView wv;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocumentSource = printDocument.DocumentSource;
        printDocument.Paginate += OnPrintDocumentPaginate;
        printDocument.GetPreviewPage += OnPrintDocumentGetPreviewPage;
        printDocument.AddPages += OnPrintDocumentAddPages;
        wv = FindName("webviewPrint") as WebView;            
    }

    private void OnPrintDocumentAddPages(object sender, AddPagesEventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument.AddPage(wv);
        printDocument.AddPagesComplete();
    }

    private void OnPrintDocumentGetPreviewPage(object sender, GetPreviewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument.SetPreviewPage(e.PageNumber, wv);
    }

    private void OnPrintDocumentPaginate(object sender, PaginateEventArgs e)
    {
        printDocument.SetPreviewPageCount(1, PreviewPageCountType.Final);            
    }

    private void OnPrintManagerPrintTaskRequested(PrintManager sender, PrintTaskRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Request.CreatePrintTask("Hello Printer", OnPrintTaskSourceRequested);

    }

    void OnPrintTaskSourceRequested(PrintTaskSourceRequestedArgs args)
    {
        args.SetSource(printDocumentSource);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintManager.GetForCurrentView().PrintTaskRequested += OnPrintManagerPrintTaskRequested;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintManager.GetForCurrentView().PrintTaskRequested -= OnPrintManagerPrintTaskRequested;
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are adding the control - and not its content - as a page to the printer document. This will simply print the visual appearance of that control. This is just a comment and not an answer because I don't know how to pass the rendered content instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Print sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Print-Sample-c544cce6) from the Official Windows SDK Samples, look at Scenario 2.  It prints content which is too large for one screen.  The sample uses a **RichTextBlock**, which you'll change to a **WebView** in your case.

Comment: Hi @Matt, I have check the sample, in scenario2, eventhough the content is very large, but all of them are rendered in the page, but the Webview has a native scrollbar, I can't print the content unless drag the scrollbar to let the content displays in the webview.